# How to find the average folder depth?

Tags: python-3.x, tree

I'm trying to solve a problem where I'm writing a function that computes the average folder depth in a tree However, the compiler tells me it cannot parse my output, here is the exact error:

```
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "solution.py", line 59, in <module>
#    res = average_folder_depth(root)
#  File "solution.py", line 27, in average_folder_depth
#    levelSum += current.self.children
#AttributeError: 'Folder' object has no attribute 'self'

from collections import deque

class Folder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []

def find_average_folder_depth(root):
    if root is None:
        return

    queue = deque()
    queue.append(root)
    while queue:
        levelSize = len(square)
        levelSum = 0.0
        for _ in range(levelSize):
            current = queue.pop(0)

            if current.left:
              queue.append(current.left)
            if current.right:
              queue.append(current.right):
        result.append(levelSum / levelSize)
    return result
```

Average depth is (0+1+2+3+4+2)/6 = 2.0. In memory, the folder tree is represented as follows:

```
ROOT
 |---A   
 |   |---B
 |   |   |---C
 |   |   |   |---D
 |   |  
 |   |
 |   |---E
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's the `current.self.children`. The `self` keyword is only needed internally when defining instance methods/variables in your class. Once an instance has been created, you call methods/attributes without it.

Try: `current.children`

Comment: That change now gives a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for += 'int' and 'list'.

Comment: what about `levelSum += sum(current.children)`, since I'm assuming `Folder.children` is a list, you need the total number of children to add to an `int` or `float` (which is `levelSum`'s type)